# Using Python, can I send a Raspberry Pi GPIO input as a HID keypress or command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi-zero

I am working on modifying existing code that works to use a Raspberry Pi as a bluetooth HID keyboard and mouse. The existing code works well to send keypresses to my Macbook via bluetooth.

What I am struggling with is converting GPIO inputs from the Raspberry Pi to a command or keypress that is sent via Bluetooth. I can make the keypresses work locally, but I can't figure out how to alter the code to accommodate GPIO input.

Ideally, I'd like to use a button to either press "Command+Right Arrow" or use AppleScript to send a Next Track command to Spotify on the Macbook. It's the only keypress I'd need to code.

I imagine I need to import GPIO and set it to BCM and then have it convert inputs from pin 4 to an AppleScript command that is sent. I just can't figure out where to do it.

The existing code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
# Thanhle Bluetooth keyboard emulation service
# keyboard copy client.
# Reads local key events and forwards them to the btk_server DBUS service
#
import os  # used to all external commands
import sys  # used to exit the script
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import time
import evdev  # used to get input from the keyboard
from evdev import *
import keymap  # used to map evdev input to hid keodes


# Define a client to listen to local key events
class Keyboard():

    def __init__(self):
        # the structure for a bt keyboard input report (size is 10 bytes)

        self.state = [
            0xA1,  # this is an input report
            0x01,  # Usage report = Keyboard
            # Bit array for Modifier keys
            [0,  # Right GUI - Windows Key
             0,  # Right ALT
             0,  # Right Shift
             0,  # Right Control
             0,  # Left GUI
             0,  # Left ALT
             0,  # Left Shift
             0],  # Left Control
            0x00,  # Vendor reserved
            0x00,  # rest is space for 6 keys
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00]

        print("setting up DBus Client")

        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.btkservice = self.bus.get_object(
            'org.thanhle.btkbservice', '/org/thanhle/btkbservice')
        self.iface = dbus.Interface(self.btkservice, 'org.thanhle.btkbservice')
        print("waiting for keyboard")
        # keep trying to key a keyboard
        have_dev = False
        while have_dev == False:
            try:
                # try and get a keyboard - should always be event0 as
                # we're only plugging one thing in
                self.dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/event0")
                have_dev = True
            except OSError:
                print("Keyboard not found, waiting 3 seconds and retrying")
                time.sleep(3)
            print("found a keyboard")

    def change_state(self, event):
        evdev_code = ecodes.KEY[event.code]
        modkey_element = keymap.modkey(evdev_code)

        if modkey_element > 0:
            if self.state[2][modkey_element] == 0:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 1
            else:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 0
        else:
            # Get the keycode of the key
            hex_key = keymap.convert(ecodes.KEY[event.code])
            # Loop through elements 4 to 9 of the inport report structure
            for i in range(4, 10):
                if self.state[i] == hex_key and event.value == 0:
                    # Code 0 so we need to depress it
                    self.state[i] = 0x00
                elif self.state[i] == 0x00 and event.value == 1:
                    # if the current space if empty and the key is being pressed
                    self.state[i] = hex_key
                    break

    # poll for keyboard events
    def event_loop(self):
        for event in self.dev.read_loop():
            # only bother if we hit a key and its an up or down event
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY and event.value < 2:
                self.change_state(event)
                self.send_input()

    # forward keyboard events to the dbus service
    def send_input(self):
        bin_str = ""
        element = self.state[2]
        for bit in element:
            bin_str += str(bit)
        a = self.state
        print(*a)
        self.iface.send_keys(int(bin_str, 2), self.state[4:10])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("Setting up keyboard")

    kb = Keyboard()

    print("starting event loop")
    kb.event_loop()
```

When I set the Raspberry Pi to read keypresses from GPIO using Retrogame or other code, it will read the keys, but it won't convert them to keypresses in the keyboard python program. It seems like it needs to be done in the code.

Edited to add more information:

The code also includes this Python file that is called "send_string.py".

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os  # used to all external commands
import sys  # used to exit the script
import dbus
import dbus.service
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import time
# import thread
import keymap


class BtkStringClient():
    # constants
    KEY_DOWN_TIME = 0.01
    KEY_DELAY = 0.01

    def __init__(self):
        # the structure for a bt keyboard input report (size is 10 bytes)
        self.state = [
            0xA1,  # this is an input report
            0x01,  # Usage report = Keyboard
            # Bit array for Modifier keys
            [0,  # Right GUI - Windows Key
                 0,  # Right ALT
                 0,  # Right Shift
                 0,  # Right Control
                 0,  # Left GUI
                 0,  # Left ALT
                 0,  # Left Shift
                 0],  # Left Control
            0x00,  # Vendor reserved
            0x00,  # rest is space for 6 keys
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00]
        self.scancodes = {
            "-": "KEY_MINUS",
            "=": "KEY_EQUAL",
            ";": "KEY_SEMICOLON",
            "'": "KEY_APOSTROPHE",
            "`": "KEY_GRAVE",
            "\\": "KEY_BACKSLASH",
            ",": "KEY_COMMA",
            ".": "KEY_DOT",
            "/": "KEY_SLASH",
            "_": "key_minus",
            "+": "key_equal",
            ":": "key_semicolon",
            "\"": "key_apostrophe",
            "~": "key_grave",
            "|": "key_backslash",
            "<": "key_comma",
            ">": "key_dot",
            "?": "key_slash",
            " ": "KEY_SPACE",
        }

        # connect with the Bluetooth keyboard server
        print("setting up DBus Client")
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.btkservice = self.bus.get_object(
            'org.thanhle.btkbservice', '/org/thanhle/btkbservice')
        self.iface = dbus.Interface(self.btkservice, 'org.thanhle.btkbservice')

    def send_key_state(self):
        """sends a single frame of the current key state to the emulator server"""
        bin_str = ""
        element = self.state[2]
        for bit in element:
            bin_str += str(bit)
        self.iface.send_keys(int(bin_str, 2), self.state[4:10])

    def send_key_down(self, scancode, modifiers):
        """sends a key down event to the server"""
        self.state[2] = modifiers
        self.state[4] = scancode
        self.send_key_state()

    def send_key_up(self):
        """sends a key up event to the server"""
        self.state[4] = 0
        self.send_key_state()

    def send_string(self, string_to_send):
        for c in string_to_send:
            cu = c.upper()
            modifiers = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
            if cu in self.scancodes:
                scantablekey = self.scancodes[cu]
                if scantablekey.islower():
                    modifiers = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
                    scantablekey = scantablekey.upper()
            else:
                if c.isupper():
                    modifiers = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
                scantablekey = "KEY_" + cu

            scancode = keymap.keytable[scantablekey]
            self.send_key_down(scancode, modifiers)
            time.sleep(BtkStringClient.KEY_DOWN_TIME)
            self.send_key_up()
            time.sleep(BtkStringClient.KEY_DELAY)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
        print("Usage: send_string <string to send>")
        exit()
    dc = BtkStringClient()
    string_to_send = sys.argv[1]
    print("Sending " + string_to_send)
    dc.send_string(string_to_send)
    print("Done.")
```

Edit #2:

Is this close to what could work with a way to poll for GPIO events?

```
    # poll for keyboard events
    def event_loop(self):
        global cmd
        for event in self.dev.read_loop():
            # only bother if we hit a key and its an up or down event
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY and event.value < 2:
                self.change_state(event)
                self.send_input()
        while True:
            if event.type == GPIO.input(4):
                self.change_state(event)
                cmd = """osascript -e 'tell app "Spotify" next track'"""            
                self.nextrack(self)
                time.sleep(.25)
                
    # forward keyboard events to the dbus service

    def nextrack(self):
        global cmd
        bin_str = ""
        element = self.state[2]
        for bit in element:
            bin_str += str(bit)
        a = self.state
        print("Play next track")
        cmd = """osascript -e 'tell app "Spotify" next track'"""
        self.iface.send_keys(os.system(cmd))
```

Comment: You need to spawn off a second thread that does nothing but poll your GPIO pin(s), waiting for a change in state.  It will send send keystrokes.  Use `time.sleep` in the loop so you don't monopolize the interpreter.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'll edit the end of the first post with what I think you're suggesting. I added it to the end. Do I then make a specific command send instead of a variable?

Comment: Sort of.  It will be a `while True:` loop that runs forever.  The loop reads the GPIO state, compares to the last state, and takes action or does a callback if the state changes, then sleeps briefly.

Comment: @TimRoberts 
Something like:
        while True:
            if event.type == GPIO.input(4):
                self.change_state(event)
                self.send_nextrack()
                time.sleep(.25)

I updated the original question again.

Comment: No.  There is no "event" when a GPIO flips.  You have to go out and read the state yourself, every single time.  You can't do this in your Bluetooth event loop, because that loop will block for long period when there's no Bt activity.  It needs to a SEPARATE loop, in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def gpioThread():
    state = GPIO.input(4)
    while True:
        now = GPIO.input(4)
        if now != state:
            # Take action here based on whether "now" is 0 or 1.
            state = now
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Then you'll have to use

```
t = Threading.thread(target=gpioThread)
t.run()
```

to create and run the thread.  Make sure you set the pin to "input" mode.  GPIO pins can be one or the other, but only one at a time.

This is typical of an Rpi program -- lots of little threads running full time doing tiny tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this today. I appreciate your help. I'm still new to the language and doing as many tutorials and online courses as I can fit into my schedule. Your help with this issue is really appreciated.